# MuMin dredge gam with random effect

Tags: gam, mumin

I am using the dredge function from the MuMin package for a gam with a random effect:

The global model using bam from the package mgcv is below.  The random effect is`s(StationID, bs = 're')`

```
gam_global<-bam(Numberpertow ~ s(interval,k=6)+Stratum+ClosArea+CruiseID+s(interval, by=CruiseID,k=6)+offset(offset)+s(StationID, bs = 're'),data=l.data,method = "REML",family=nb(),na.action = "na.fail")
```

When I run the dredge function on the global model the random effect is dropped from a subset of the models as dredge is running through the different model options with and without certain variables.  I am not interested in determining if the random effect is needed and need to keep it in all models as the random effect.  I also need to retain the offset term in all models.

After conducting a web search, I tried the following based on this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064080/fixed-terms-in-dredge-function-mumin-in-gam[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064080/fixed-terms-in-dredge-function-mumin-in-gam%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064080/fixed-terms-in-dredge-function-mumin-in-gam.)

I tried the following two approaches with no success:

```
#genertric random effect name as shown in model summary output

gam_dredge<-dredge(gam_global,evaluate=TRUE,fixed=c("offset(offset)","s(StationID)"),rank="AIC")

#random effect name as in model

gam_dredge<-dredge(gam_global,evaluate=TRUE,fixed=c("offset(offset)","s(StationID,bs="re)"),rank="AIC")
```

I have also changed the method in the bam model from `REML` to `GCV.Cp`

I have had no success with any iteration of dredge and get the following when the dredge chuck is run:

```
Fixed terms are "offset(offset)" and "(Intercept)"
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you don't do this; it is a statistical travesty in general and I have no idea what the extra complexity of choose smoothness parameters for a set of model terms while simultaneously dropping other model terms will do to this process. Unless you are going for a purely predictive model, you would be better off using `select = TRUE` to put extra penalties on the perfectly smooth parts of each basis (so that they can be shrunken effectively out of the model). By the way, for `bam()` you want `method = "fREML"` otherwise you throw away one of the benefits of `bam()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When you say statistical travesty, are you referring to using dredge?  I was investigating this approach because a reviewer wanted all combinations of predictor variables as model options.   I did end up using method="fREML" and also not using dredge.

Answer (score 0):

White space matters. The model term name is `'s(StationID, bs = "re")'`.

As per `?dredge`, "the term names appearing in `fixed` and `subset` must be in the exact form returned by getAllTerms(global.model)". For this reason, the accepted SO answer you referenced is incorrect (this is why the manual should always be the primary source of information).

However, you can make things easier by giving `fixed` as a formula, in which case white space is irrelevant (outside of character strings):

```
~ offset(    offset) + s  (StationID,      bs  ="re"  )
```